# Null divergence of magnetic field: a mathematical approach

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, physics, partial-derivative

My textbook of physics, Gettys's *Physics* (Italian language edition), says that the Lorenz gauge choice uses the magnetic vector potential $$\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x},t):=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{y},t-c^{-1}\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|)}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}d\mu_{\mathbf{y}} $$ where $\mathbf{J}:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is a function satisfying the assumptions given in physics, like differentiability and being zero outside $R\times\mathbb{R}$ where $R\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a bounded domain, $\mu_0$ is magnetic permeability and $c$ is the speed of light.

How can we prove that such an $\mathbf{A}$ satisfies Maxwell's equation $$\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times\mathbf{A})=0?$$
Problems arise since I am not sure whether and how we could differentiate under the integral sign, and I am asking here rather than in PSE because I notice that questions focussing on mathematical derivations tend to be redirected here.

Comment: **HINT:**

Let $\vec r=\vec y-\vec x$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathscr{R}^3}\frac{\vec J(\vec y,t-\frac1c|\vec y-\vec x|)}{|\vec y-\vec x|}d\mu_{\vec y}&=\int_{\mathscr{R}^3} \frac{\vec J(\vec r+\vec x,t-\frac1c|\vec r|)}{|\vec r|}d\mu_{\vec r}\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty \vec J\left(\vec r+\vec x,t-\frac rc \right)\,r\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Dr.MV I thank you so much for the hint! Nevertheless, I don't see how this facilitates differentiation (under the integral sign?)...

Comment: There is no singularity now.

Comment: @Dr.MV And we can differentiate $\mathbf{J}$ under the integral sign, since the domain of integration can be chosen to be compact under the assumption that $\mathbf{J}$ is zero outside $R\times\mathbb{R}$ (as defined in the OP). If $\mathbf\nabla_x\cdot(\nabla_x\times\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x},t))\equiv 0$ we are done; is it $0$ under some assumption on $\mathbf{J}$?

Comment: That sounds correct.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you so much!

Comment: And in case you were unaware, $\nabla \cdot \nabla. \times \vec A=0$ is simply a vector identity.